# How to reduce “Connecting” time incurred for a request

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, gtmetrix

I am trying to optimize speed of website and during this process I have found that. A connecting time of around 117ms is incurred every time I request a page. Please see screenshot below for detailed information
[image]
This is persistent. Is there any way to reduce this time? What could be the possible reasons:

Is this because of SSL? This website is only accessible.
Or is it an issue with DNS? I am using Godaddy DNS as of now. Will switching to AWS Route 53 provide any benefit.
I am using apache server.

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to multiple reasons

1. Slow hosting(upgrade if slow).
2. Hosting location(Use CDN if required).
3. Plugins/scripts slowing down your site(create and test with html page with just text in it).